# Should closed questions be excluded from the front page?

Tags: support

Right now on https://ux.stackexchange.com/ there are four questions with negative vote scores, and three of them are closed.

Isn't the front page supposed to include the [greatest hits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91661/main-navigation-questions-vs-home/91870#91870)?

Comment: The "front page" is a very odd entity really. It's showing the most recently edited items, and doesn't exist as a tab like "questions", and it has a few weird subtabs. I assume you're talking about the "active" subtab of the main page? I would posit that once an item it is closed it is not, by definition, "active" though so I don't think these should go on the "active" tab at all.

Comment: @BenBrocka By "front page," I mean the home page, where you go when you click the logo. The active tab is selected by default. It's subtly different to the /questions page, and I agree, it's weird. The subject has come up before on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91661/main-navigation-questions-vs-home/91870).

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember with closed questions is that they can be reopened.

If you hide them from the front page then people will have to go looking for them (via the tools menu or by custom searches). Thus it will be harder for borderline questions to be found, edited into shape and then reopened than now.

This will mean that closing becomes permanent rather than something that can be - and should be seen to be - temporary.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense for the active tab under /questions, but not for /, and particularly not for unregistered users.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney the active tab is /, isn't it (for "top questions")? It appears to be the default even when I view the page logged out.

I do agree borderline questions would be harder to find, but, especially for new/unregistered users I'm not sure that's a bad thing.

Comment: I'm not wedded to having closed question appearing on the home page. Having them *does* make tag cleanups etc. much harder as editing old, closed questions makes them reappear which is the last thing you want to do.

Comment: Maybe instead of cleaning up tags on old, closed questions, they should just get deleted over time.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung - probably true, but a point worth considering. If the question's been cleaned up then it needs to be visible to get the other reopen votes it needs.

Comment: If you're cleaning up the actual question, sure. I was really just talking about the times where we decide to clean up tags (as you mentioned). A closed question that hasn't been touched in 6 months (just throwing out a random interval) should probably just be deleted rather than updating just the tags.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung - yeah - "tag cleanups" was a bad example!

Comment: @CharlesBoyung I wouldn't support deleting them automatically, plenty of useful and or popular questions are closed on sites because they're not very QnA or they're duplicates (duplicates with different titles can help searches find the original question thread)

Comment: @BenBrocka - Non-Q&A questions *should* get deleted. And duplicates should get merged with the original if there's content worth keeping. Otherwise, the duplicates don't really provide value.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung - Duplicates do provide some value - they're an alternate way of finding the same content. Different words, phrases etc. However, not all duplicates do.

Comment: I for one like having documentation of old closed questions. It helps aid the decision to close a new one, or at least to act as a precedent.